# Слово "скоропостижно": можно ли употреблять не только в контексте смерти?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, стилистика, семантика, смысл

Судя по всему, слово "скоропостижно/скоропостижный" употребляется в основном в отношении смерти (скоропостижная смерть, скоропостижно скончался и т. д.). Однако ведь в литературе встречаются и другие значения, которые ближе к просто "неожиданно/быстро/поспешно" (см. [Нацкорпус](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE)).

Так вот, в каких ситуациях возможно употребление слова "скоропостижно/скоропостижный" в его реже встречающемся значении? Имею в виду, считается ли это значение устаревшим или просто редко используемым? И в каких случаях употребление этого слова в значении, не связанном со смертью (или отдалённо связанном), можно считать стилистически оправданным, не будет ли это ошибкой? Могу предположить, что как минимум в юмористическом ключе такое возможно, наподобие: "Его и без того нежеланно рождённое выступление **скоропостижно** завершилось".

Comment: Ответы на свои вопросы оформлять следует не дополнением, а отдельным ответом на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что ж, попробую сам разобраться...

Если посмотреть по словарям, в некоторых из них при слове "скоропостижный"  присутствует пометка о том, что оно обычно употребляется в контексте смерти. Например.

СКОРОПОСТИ́ЖНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -жен, -жна, -жно. Внезапный, неожиданный (**обычно о смерти**). Смерть бедной Татьяны Ивановны была скоропостижная. Достоевский, Село Степанчиково (Словарь русского языка под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой); см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

СКОРОПОСТИ'ЖНЫЙ, ая, ое; -жен, жна, жно (книжн.). Внезапный, неожиданный (**теперь преимущ. о смерти**). Скоропостижная кончина. Скоропостижная смерть. Скончаться скоропостижно (нареч.) («Толковый словарь русского языка» под редакцией Д. Н. Ушакова (1935-1940); см. также [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

СКОРОПОСТИЖНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -жен, -жна, -жно. Внезапный, неожиданный (**обычно о смерти**). С-ая смерть. С. отъезд. <Скоропостижно, нареч. С. умереть, скончаться. С. жениться (**шутл.**). Скоропостижность, -и; ж. С. кончины (Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов); см. [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x).

Однако, как видно из последней выдержки, "скоропостижно" и правда может употребляться в шутливой манере, например в значении "жениться" (пометка "шутл.").

В "Нацкорпусе" есть множество примеров, когда "скоропостижный" или "скоропостижно" употреблены не в контексте смерти, а в юмористичной манере или же просто в значении "неожиданно быстро, внезапно". Приведу лишь несколько.

**1.** Наречие "скоропостижно"

*То **скоропостижно заболевает** один адвокат, потом другой внезапно уходит в отпуск, а третий исчезает неведомо куда. [Беззащитная братва // «Криминальная хроника», 2003.07.08]*

*Падение. Сказка закончилась прозаично: пробыв "дворянкой столбовою" от силы полтора года, клуб **скоропостижно вернулся** к разбитому корыту, а уже в 96-м навсегда исчез из поля зрения высшей лиги. [Высоко взлетать -- больно падать. Краткая история российской футбольной провинции // «Известия», 2001.07.27]*

*Первого декабря природа как бы заглянула в календарь и, спохватившись, что пора перейти к зимним своим обязанностям, выдала настоящий холод. Температура **скоропостижно упала** до 12 градусов. Земля окоченела, лужи затянуло льдом, и что-то противоестественное было в этой бесснежной морозности. [Л. А. Левицкий. Дневник (1978)]*

*Потом Козинец ссорился с Мардановой из-за привлечения её ученика к импровизации «Буревестника» Горького и с Ярошевским, который провел в 11-м классе «час» на тему о «советском браке». Потом Черную **скоропостижно принимали** в партию. [В. А. Швец. Дневник (1960)]*

*Почему мы так **скоропостижно улепетнули** из столицы? [Г. С. Эфрон. Дневники. Т. 1. 1941 (1941)]*

**2.** Прилагательное "скоропостижный"

*Впрочем, в ответ на **скоропостижный отказ** суда трем первым истцам было подано сразу несколько новых исков. [Александр Агеев. Северный ветер (2003) // «Профиль», 03.02.2003]*

*Его **скоропостижный брак** тоже начался с шепота о помощи. [Дарья Симонова. Без Россини (2002)]*

*(До падрэ уже дошло известие, что Лоренцо видели рано утром на дороге к Ливорно, и он понял все, что значил и предвещал этот **скоропостижный отъезд**). [Е. П. Ростопчина. Палаццо Форли (1854)]*

*Иногда находит **скоропостижный жар** или стужа, вступает в лицо бледность, болезнь в голову или другие члены, мысли притом опускаются и ко всяким крепким движениям бывают склонны. [М. В. Ломоносов. О сохранении здравия [перевод] (1741)]*

Стало быть, слово "скоропостижно" ("скоропостижный") авторы разных лет действительно употребляют не только в контексте смерти, но и в значении "внезапно", "неожиданно" ("скоропостижный отъезд" и пр.), в том числе в юмористическом ключе ("скоропостижно улепетнули" и др.).

Наконец даже "Грамота.ру" ответила, что это слово может употребляться вне контекста смерти, в шутливом ключе (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309700)).

> Слова *скоропостижный*, *скоропостижно* обычно употребляют, когда речь идет о смерти: *скоропостижная смерть*, *скоропостижно скончался*. Сочетания с другими словами (например, *скоропостижно жениться*, *скоропостижно вылечиться*) возможны, но они будут иметь шутливый оттенок.

**3.** Вывод

Слово "скоропостижно" не возбраняется использовать как синоним к "неожиданно", "внезапно", — это его значение не является устаревшим, а попросту реже употребляется.

Comment: Shi Komarishe, Ваш ответ правильный, но чересчур длинный, поэтому плохо воспринимается. Я бы его подкоротила, если Вы не против.

Comment: Римма, можете попробовать, ладно. Я пытался убедительно ответить, с примерами, вот и длинновато получилось...

Comment: Римма, а почему вы убрали в ответе оформление цитирования (из словарей и "Нацкорпуса")? Мне казалось, оно как раз уместно в таких случаях. Или здесь сложились другие негласные правила оформления? Что тогда надо оформлять цитатой, а что нет?

Comment: Дело тут не в негласных правилах. 1. О словарях. Если ставится знак цитирования, то весь текст должен быть таким же, как и у автора, в том числе и его выделение — **жирным** или *курсивом*. У Вас это было упущено. 2. О Нацкорпусе. Вы ведь в ответе уже предупредили: *В "Нацкорпусе" есть множество примеров... Приведу лишь несколько.* И приводите их друг за другом с указанием **авторства**. В этом случае лучше не ставить знаки цитирования (они образовывают пропуски не в одну строку, а в три). При большом количестве примеров эта длинная поперечная линия мешает.

Comment: Хорошо, вроде бы понял суть. Буду стараться:)

Comment: Рада, что мы поняли друг друга. Вот и Вы моё упущение заметили и исправили. Бонус — с удовольствием!